# A default generic parameter applied on instance a generic class which has no default generic parameters

Tags: typescript

```
class Base<T extends number>{

}

const ins = new Base // works, T is number although which is not passed

class Child extends Base { // Type error, base needs a generic parameter

}
```

Why we could instance Base while not passing generic parameter?

Comment: This isn't a *default*, but a result of *inference*.  When you write `new Base()` you are calling a generic construct signature which (like all generic function calls) supports *type argument inference* where the compiler tries to infer `T` for you (it essentially fails, since `T` is unused in your class definition, but it falls back to the `number` constraint). ...

Comment: ... Class extension on the other hand does *not* support type argument inference; it behaves more like a generic *type* and you need to explicitly specify the argument. There's an open feature request at [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) asking for more control over type arg inference, but for now it's not part of the language. Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write this up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?